# GeoPy is not working: What is the reason of NOT getting results for nom.geocode()?

Tags: python-3.x, geopy

I have already installed certificates (used this advice from a different thread) .[Here's the code and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9tf4.jpg)

```
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS

nom = ArcGIS()
location=nom.geocode("3995 23rd st, San Francisco, CA 94114",timeout=180)
print(location)
```

What's the problem? I am not getting results for longitude/latitude.
how to get the results?

Please help.

Comment: add the result of `print(location)`? is it printing an address instead of a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code,

```
>>> print(location)  
3995 23rd St, San Francisco, California, 94114
>>> location
Location(3995 23rd St, San Francisco, California, 94114, (37.752990821253434, -122.43170235858965, 0.0))
```

The points are in there, but `print()` doesn't print them, just the address text string associated with them.

`location` is basically a dictionary of the results returned by the geocoding service.

```
>>> type(location)
<class 'geopy.location.Location'>
>>> location.latitude
37.752990821253434
>>> location.longitude
-122.43170235858965
```

[here are the docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#geopy.location.Location) for the location class the results are stored in.